# WPF имя [Имя типа] не существует в пространстве имен clr-namespace

Tags: wpf

Всем доброго времени суток!

Имеется сторонняя библиотека и следующий код:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BatchAddingParameters.BatchAddingControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BatchAddingParameters"
         xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:rdb="clr-namespace:Autodesk.Revit.DB;assembly=RevitAPI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    </Style>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ParameterType"
            MethodName="GetValues" 
            ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="rdb:ParameterType"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Необходимо сделать следующие: создать некую DataGrid и запихнуть в данный грид ряд элементов, один из которых является выпадающий список, в который будут записаны элементы из перечисления ParameterType, который в свою очередь лежит в сторонней библиотеке. Но, возникла ошибка в строчке:

```
<x:Type TypeName="rdb:ParameterType"/>
```

Имя "ParameterType" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:Autodesk.Revit.DB;assembly=RevitAPI".

Не могу понять почему он не может вытащить это перечисление из данной библиотеки.

На просторах интернета нашел такие рекомендации как:

1. Поставить целевую платформу x86
2. Проверить библиотеку и т.д.

Соответственно, ничего из этого не помогает.

Comment: `перечисления ParameterType` - имеется ввиду `enum`?

Comment: так точно - enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, все это можно сделать программно:

```
[Имя элемента].ItemsSource = typeof(ParameterType)
                              .GetFields()
                              .Where(x => x.Name != "value__")
                              .Select(x => x.Name)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно и медленно? Почему не просто `Enum.GetValues`?

Comment: Да, так будет лучше, спасибо